# Remove / merge google-javascript-api tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I just saw we have a [google-javascript-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-javascript-api) tag which looks like a quite broad tag and has no description.

We already have [google-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api) which is for *any* API provided by Google.

I believe we could merge both tags together. Each Google Javascript API that I know of already have their own tag (Google Maps, Roads, Places, Directions, Geocoding, Visualization, etc.)

**Edit**: Following the discussion in the comments, it was pointed out that we have a [google-api-python-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-python-client), a [google-api-php-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-php-client) tag, and other similar tags for the different clients.

If we find out or believe the [google-javascript-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-javascript-api) tag was created for questions related to the [Google API Client Library for JavaScript](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) then we should probably rename that tag to `google-api-javascript-client`.

Comment: Would there be subject matter experts on the Google-API that are only interested in answering Google-javascript-api questions? Is that concept even a thing? There is also a [tag:google-api-python-client], maybe that was also meant for the tag that is being discussed? I could find other popular language clients.

Comment: That's an interesting one - I agree. [tag:google-javascript-api] tends to be used with [tag:google-api] regardless. Plus, I thought we had sort of a consensus for these tags: api + language + [ api-specific tag ]. For what its worth, I think it should be: [tag:javascript] [tag:google-api]

Comment: @OlegValter I agree. Each specific API has its own tag AFAIK. I personally wouldn't tag a question specific to one of their APIs with `google-api` and that tag itself is questionable IMO. But a combination of `google-api` and `javascript` tags seems appropriate for *(too?)* broad questions on any Google JS API.

Comment: @MrUpsidown - hope you won't respark one-tag / two-tags discussion :) That said, I also agree with rene's concern - that language-specific API libraries tags exist. I think if you are ready to defend the position, a broader discussion for consensus can be started. Otherwise, the tag can be safely retagged and then synonymized / removed - no one even bothered to give it a wiki (while the opposite is true for Python library)

Comment: Whether a tag has a wiki or not shouldn't be a reason to keep it or delete it. If the tag makes sense, we should keep it. If it needs a wiki, we should write one. The python *client* related tag points to a specific API client. If the tag I mentioned was supposed to exist for the JS client, then I believe it should be renamed to `google-api-javascript-client` and point to https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client.

Comment: @MrUpsidown - well, I just meant that since it does not even have a wiki *and* you have a valid point of the purpose of the tag better served by other means - the tag could be dealt with without much opposition (by renaming / retagging / merging / deleting - whatever the decision is). My thoughts are that it was indeed intended to represent API language-specific client library, so a rename + tag wiki creation would be a good idea (I would create one myself, but I have 5 pending already and cannot add another)

Comment: For reference of readers: [tag:google-api-php-client], [tag:google-api-python-client], [tag:google-api-ruby-client], [tag:google-api-java-client], [tag:google-api-go-client], [tag:google-api-dotnet-client]. Google Apps Script has advanced services as a stand-in

Comment: It would also be great if we had a reference to these language-specific tags in the wiki of the main [google-api] tag, just like we do with [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-sheets/info) and a lot of other tags

Comment: @OlegValter agreed and I'll be happy to do it once we have done the proposed changes.

Comment: @MrUpsidown - btw, I got a couple of slots freed up, so working on it - wanted to visually separate deprecated APIs + provide links to guides / references for the listed APIs for quite some time

Answer (score 5):

**Proposal**

As per discussion and given the fact that JavaScript API client library is the only one deviating from the convention (see [google-api-php-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-php-client), [google-api-python-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-python-client), [google-api-ruby-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-ruby-client), [google-api-java-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-java-client), [google-api-go-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-go-client), [google-api-dotnet-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-dotnet-client) for reference),

It is proposed to adopt the following course of action:

1. Renaming [google-javascript-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-javascript-api) to [google-api-javascript-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-javascript-client) as this is how it is [named in the repo](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) or to [google-api-browser-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-browser-client) as referenced in API-specific guides (see [Sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js), [Calendar](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js), [Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js)).
2. Creating [tag wiki and excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-javascript-api/info) with a [reference to API library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library) and its [repository](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client)
3. Including "related tags" section in [google-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api) tag wiki
   (using built-in "related tags" feature would require duplication with adding [google-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api) tag)
4. Add relevant "use for" and "do not use" sections to [google-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-api/info) with clarifications about using the tag for non library-specific issues with Google APIs

---

An alternative thanks to MrUpsidown's find that we *do* have a [google-api-js-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-js-client) tag with a wiki and appx. 2e2 questions would be to:

1. Rename [google-api-js-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-js-client) to [google-api-javascript-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-javascript-client)
2. Merge [google-javascript-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-javascript-api) with [google-api-javascript-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-javascript-client) as the former has only 55 questions so far and no wiki
3. Synonymize [google-api-browser-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-browser-client) with [google-api-javascript-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-javascript-client) since this is the second naming convention for the library

The rest of the points that do not conflict with the alternative still apply.

Comment: There should be two, really, [google-api-javascript-client] (or [google-api-browser-client], which would be more accurate) and [google-api-node.js-client]. I've already seen questions confusing the two clients (trying to use the Node.js client in a browser, for instance).

Comment: @HereticMonkey - hm, that's a very good point - and it is officially named that way. It may indeed reduce confusion about Node.js and JavaScript libraries. Maybe even like this: rename to [tag:google-api-browser-client], then synonymize [google-api-javascript-client] to it (in case questions creep up)

Comment: We should be careful about that, as there is the NodeJS client (which is obviously also written in JavaScript, but differently)...

Comment: The "officially named" link you provided (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) is about the Google Sheets API which is another thing. The main JS API client is [Google API Client Library for JavaScript](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) which should be `google-api-javascript-client` if we keep the same naming *convention*.

Comment: @MrUpsidown - well, I guess I worded it very poorly... I meant this is how it is referenced in API-specific pages: [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js), for example. That said, I also understand that this it is [named as you mentioned](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) I am worried about what Heretic Monkey pointed out - potential to confusion with Node.js. But I am also for keeping the convention, so I am torn on the matter.

Comment: @OlegValter Got you. I don't think it would be really confusing if we had [google-api-javascript-client] **and** [google-api-node.js-client]. We need tag wikis though. I just found out though that we also have [tag:google-api-js-client] which seems to be yet another naming for that same *Google API Client Library for JavaScript*. Do we want "js" or "javascript"? I don't know what's the naming convention. I would choose "javascript".

Comment: At some point, I think we should take a decision on *what* tags we want to have and a real *naming convention* towards these Google-related tags. I have other requests in the pipe for Google APIs... The point is, Google provides dozens of APIs. Many can be accessed as web services, **and** with client libraries. Also Google has renamed some of those APIs over the time. I believe all these points have lead to the current situation with inconsistent naming. Also some tags were obviously created with no real naming convention in mind. Do we want to harmonise everything?

Comment: @MrUpsidown - good find, looks like there is another venue given what you found: rename [tag:google-api-js-client] to [tag:google-api-javascript-client], then add [tag:google-api-browser-client] as synonym and if [tag:google-api-js-client] still creeps up, make it a synonym as well. I would also choose JavaScript (not sure about the consensus either, but my guideline always was: use the name given by creator where possible).

Comment: @MrUpsidown - re: convention - I would say we should, after all, that what meta is for - if we can coordinate the effort, the better of we will be when answering (I am personally tired of removing [tag:google-sheets-api] from questions about [tag:google-sheets], for example). Chit-chat aside, one thing is consistent, though: there are client libraries, APIs, and products. Currently, we have all three sort of mixed in one pot... We are already trying to get things straight with Google Apps Script part of things, so it would be a good idea to cleanup the bigger picture as well

Comment: I am not too familiar with such tasks. Should I create a separate support request here and list all what I think needs to be done? I know probably all their Maps / Places related APIs but definitely not all Google APIs and I don't know to what extent the related tags need some work. In short, how should we approach that "cleanup" task?

Comment: I am currently working on improving the APIs wiki to include references, separate deprecated APIs from current, group them by product where possible, etc. Google APIs is a confusing topic indeed - there are so many of them... As @CodyGray mentioned - it is preferred to keep merge / delete / rename requests by-task separate, but the overall effort could be coordinated in a separate Q&A (we did just that and it seems to be more or less working)

Comment: Btw, if anyone knows *for sure* what happened to these APIs listed please ping me while I am still editing, these are the ones I could not find any info concrete info on:  
 - Enterprise Audit API 
 - Google App State API
 - Google OAuth2 API (does this refer to Google Sign In?)
 - Google Play MDM API (there is a EMM API, but I need a domain expert to cust judgement)

Comment: Oh, god, I am done. Tag wiki update for Google APIs finished (sort of - there are still tags missing, tags named disregarding convention, confusing APIs, etc, etc, etc. I will make a separate post about it when ready). Edit is now pending: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26575793