# Google-api-v3 tag should be removed

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Sadly, I am not allowed to delete this tag, can someone please set it as a synonym for me please to, say, [google-maps-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api) or [google-drive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api).

[image: tag synonyms page screenshot with error]

I have retagged all questions currently using this tag, but having the tag here will simply cause confusion.

Comment: Frankly, I think we should also deal away with the [tag:google-api] tag as well while you are at it. I once tried to clean it up and mostly did (by updating the list of tags to point to relevant API-specific tags and pruning the deprecated ones), but it is literally unmaintainable and very unnecessary (can we talk about [tag:google-api] without talking about a specific API? Not counting the cases where questions are *literally* generic, but that's not the usage so far)

Comment: I would rather you left the Google-api tag, this is used to tag all google discovery services apis, its useful because all of these apis use generated client libraries which means a lot of the code and examples use to with one will work with another.  Oauth, download, upload ... for example.     Its very maintainable i have been maintaining it for seven years that's why i have a Gold tag badge in it.

Comment: I think the better name is google-common-api, rather than just google-api.

Comment: If you want to argue google-api tag that should be in a different question really

Comment: Yeah, that's the usage I tried to refer to in the "generic" case. It is useful to have if used properly, just that something needs to be done to it probably to stop people from using it as catch-all tag to questions and probably to the list of "all-the-tags-google" that's its wiki. It was a painful experience to work through :)

Comment: @OlegValter its really not a catch all its an added tag. and its only the [discovery services](https://developers.google.com/discovery) apis not ALL google apis, maps and cloud APIs do not fall under this tag.

Comment: @DaImTo that's just an off-note since the [google-api] related effort came up again, apologies if you think that interferes with the question. Anyways, as with the v4, it is probably the best to just prune it (as you did) and wait 24 hours - the tag will disappear shortly after

Comment: I just wish we could come to a consensus on the google-analyitcs tag https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406188/1841839 that causes more issues than Google-api

Comment: @DaImTo - allow me just one more note to not overshadow the task in question further: I understand your position, we do not differ, I also work quite a lot with Google APIs (although not at your scale, obviously) and get the difference. Just that the tag in its current state is quite a mess (take a look at the wiki - cloud APIs, product APIs, all Google is to offer is there. And that's after the cleanup effort - so I agree with Braiam, it would benefit from a rename [not sure what would be the most beneficial name])

Comment: Im up for a clean up of the tag, and a rename, sure you dont want to open a new question and we can hash this out?   I have been baby sitting this tag for so long now its nice seeing someone else who wants to show it some love :)

Comment: @DaImTo - true, I am actually with you on the [tag:google-analytics] tag. The only issue is that the post is already a month old, so by Meta standards it is as good as dead. Probably only brining it up constantly in requests such as this can revive the discussion. I am not sure you noticed, but since tags are basically the "younger brother" of SO features, not many get excited in discussing or curating them (except for burnination requests, but they are mostly popular fo punny titles) :) P.s. [tag:google-api] methinks someone brought it up as a post before, I will try to dig it up

Comment: @OlegValter i dont monitor meta you guys scare me.

Comment: @DaImTo - I know, meta can be intimidating :) Frankly, if you did, I am not sure it is possible to keep up with everything that's going on - rabbis probably have a better time than we are. Don't worry, you are most welcome here.

Comment: @DaImTo - ah, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398967/11407695) it is (re:[tag:google-api]), although it is tied to the discussion on the [tag:google-javascript-api]. Probably worth starting a separate discussion on fixing the tag. Since I predict a huge mess that will come out of it, will likely do that closer to the end of the week.

Comment: Synonyms seems to be a bad solution for this. Synonyms don't delete the tag, they continue to exist, just silently changed to something else. We have to be very careful when suggest synonyms.

Comment: @Braiam i was unaware of any other option to remove a tag and have it no longer be able to be used by anyone to tag a question.

Comment: @DaImTo - to be precise, the auto removal of the tag after 24 hours is not a silver bullet, of course. It still can be recreated by anyone with as little as 1500 rep, and the blacklisting is seemingly inaccessible now ( due to the lack of a community-oriented dev in SE after Shog9 was removed from the position if I recall correctly )